# How can I re-require in ruby?

Tags: ruby

How can I re-require in ruby?
I know about `load`, but with that, I need to specify the path. I want `ruby` to do that path lookup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`load` does not need a full path, it needs a complete filename including an extension.

Comment: Thanks. Indeed it doesn't! Because of the extension requirement I kind of assumed it did.